# How do I create a slideshow in Angular using ngClass?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, slideshow

I am trying to create an image slider in Angular 6 but I am not able to navigate to different images. I am uploading the images using the input tag and storing them in an array called 'images'.

The active image are supposed to displayed within the constraints of the slideshow container and the image to be displayed can be chosen by clicking on the indicating dots below it. I've so far tried to bind a class to the img element to display the active image. One of the problems is that only 1 dot is getting displayed.

This is my HTML page:

```
<div *ngIf="images">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <img *ngFor="let image of images; let i=index" 
            [src]="image" 
            [ngClass]="{'image-active': selectedindex == i}">  

        <div style="text-align:center"  *ngFor="let dot of images; let i=index">
            <span class="dot" 
                (click)="selectImage(i)"
                [ngClass]="{'active': selectedindex == i}">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my method to select a particular image:

```
public selectedindex: number = 0; //Initialized to 0
public images: string[] = null;

selectImage(index : number) {
    console.log("Index: "+index);
    this.selectedindex = index;
    console.log("Selected Index: "+this.selectedindex);
  }
```

And this the css:

```
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.image-active {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

/* The dots/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

As of now only one dot is getting displayed, and only the last uploaded image is visible. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some `css`

```
.slideshow-container img{
  display: none;
}

.slideshow-container img.image-active {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

check your [snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eih857) with updated code

Comment: I am still not able to get more than one dot to appear. Whenever I upload a new image it gets added to the array and the image in the display gets replaced by the new one. But the number of dots does not increase.

Comment: Have you checked in snippet? there is displaying dot as per images